# Convention for DatabaseGeneratedOption.None

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I would like to manually insert id for all my entities.
Is it possible to create some kind of convention or I have to set HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None) (or add DatabaseGenerated attribute) for every entity ?

**EDIT**

There is a simpler way to do this then using accepted answer:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<StoreGeneratedIdentityKeyConvention>();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to create custom conventions in EntityFramework 6 as follows:

**Create a convention class**

```
public class ManualIdentityConvention : Convention
{
    public ManualIdentityConvention()
    {
        this.Properties<int>()
            .Where(p => p.Name.EndsWith("Id"))
            .Configure(p => p.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None));
    }
}
```

**Add the convention to your DbContext**

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new ManualIdentityConvention());
    }
}
```

**EntityFramework 5**

As for EntityFramework 5, I believe something similar can be achieved, but not via a convention class:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Properties<int>()
            .Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Id"))
            .Configure(x => x.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None));
    }
}
```

In either case, neither approach is particularly surgical, but one could conceivably tighten up the convention by being more specific in one's where clause.

Does this help?