# Is it possible to make Entity Framework insert primary key that I given?

Tags: entity-framework-6

I forced to work with database where tables haven't auto increment. And I can't alter it. I want to insert entity using Entity Framework. I create an object of this entity and manually set it's Id field (primay key) and then make Add and SaveChanges. But I see in log, that EF clear the value of DbParameter for Id field. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an annotation of fluent configuration to tell EF the keys are manual. See [Entering keys manually with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907411/entering-keys-manually-with-entity-framework). You could also add a custom convention to handle globally: [Convention for DatabaseGeneratedOption.None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805637/convention-for-databasegeneratedoption-none)

Comment: That's exactly I sought for. Thank you, Steve!