# Can't add a new record with an integer value into database by using linq from code C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, database, linq

I'm trying to build a simple ASP.NET MVC website but I encountered some problem. I can't add a new record with integer value into database by using linq command. I have a table called 'groups' in database. It's following: groups([int] [primary key] MaNhom, [char(100)] TenNhom). Explain: MaNhom is GroupID, TenNhom is GroupName. (Sorry for this convenience when I name these field by Vietnamese.). I add an ADO.NET Entity Data Model and a class called 'group.cs' is generated.

```
public partial class group
    {
        [Key]
        public int MaNhom { get; set; }
        public string TenNhom { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I also create a class in Models folder of my web project called Group.

```
public class Group
    {
        [Key]
        public int MaNhom { get; set; }
        public string TenNhom { get; set; }
    }
```

I created a view called CreateManageGroup.cshtml. The content of it is following:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateManageGroup";
}

<h2>Create A Group</h2>

<form action="/account/CreateManageGroup" method="post">
    <label for="TenNhom"> Name of Group </label>
    <input type="text" name="TenNhom" id="inputGroupName">

    <input type="submit" value="Create">
</form>
```

When I submit it, value of TenNhom will be sent to and saved in parameter 'group' of method CreateManageGroup(Group group) in AccountController.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateManageGroup(Group group)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid == true)
            {
                var newGroup = new DataAccess.group();

                newGroup.TenNhom = group.TenNhom;
                var randomObject = new Random();
                do
                {
                    newGroup.MaNhom = randomObject.Next(1, 9999);
                }
                while (DataAccess.Queries.CheckExistInGroup(newGroup.MaNhom) == true);
                DataAccess.Queries.ExcuteInsertIntoGroup(newGroup);
                return RedirectToAction("SignUp");
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

I checked and I know newGroup.MaNhom is set a value different zero after randomming, such as 3309. But after calling method ExcuteInsertIntoGroup(newGroup), value of MaNhom of table groups in database is 0. The content of ExcuteInsertIntoGroup():

```
namespace DataAccess
{
    public class Queries
    {
        public static void ExcuteInsertIntoGroup(group record)
        {

            phep_toanDatabase.groups.Add(record);
            phep_toanDatabase.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: phep_toanDatabase is variable declared in class Queries of class library DataAccess:

```
public static phep_toanEntities phep_toanDatabase;
        static DataAccess()
        {
            phep_toanDatabase = new phep_toanEntities();
        }
```

My question is: Why after excuting linq command, value of MaNhom displayed in table groups as 0 although newGroup.MaNhom is set to a value different 0 before?
Thank you!

Comment: What is `while (DataAccess.Queries.CheckExistInGroup(newGroup.MaNhom) == true);` there for?

Comment: might be unrelated, but it seems you are trying to force a random value onto a primary key column, you could simplify the process by making your `[int] [primary key] MaNhom` to also `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: @Zack Tarr: The condition means that while this value of newGroup.MaNhom (MaNhom is id of group) already existed in table 'groups', we still random it.

Answer (score 1):

actually, after posting my comment I had a bit of a brainwave, which might end up answering your question. This is a theory:

you mentioned your table is defined as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE groups(
   MaNhom INT primary key,
   TenNhom CHAR(100)
);
```

that yields an Entity, correctly decorated with `[Key]` attribute:

```cs
public partial class group
    {
        [Key]
        public int MaNhom { get; set; }
        public string TenNhom { get; set; }
    }
}
```

what I suspect happens when you call EF's .SaveChanges() is it completely ignores the value id `MaNhom` assuming that the DB will take care of it. in MySQL however, the PK will not auto-increment unless you tell it to. Which is where you need to either:

#### 1. update table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE groups(
   MaNhom INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   TenNhom CHAR(100)
);
```

#### 2. update model:

[this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28853555/is-it-possible-to-make-entity-framework-insert-primary-key-that-i-given) provides some guidance:

```cs
public partial class group
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int MaNhom { get; set; }
        public string TenNhom { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer but I have several question. I think auto_increment means that the value of this field will increase automatically. In my case, I don't need value of the field 'MaNhom' increases automatically when I add a new record. I just want to insert a new record with optional value of field MaNhom. (You can ignore my commands regarding randomming and assume that I am setting the value of newGroup.MaNhom to an optional integer). Even if I want to do that, do I still need set MaNhom as auto_increment? Thank you!

Comment: It's really hard to give you advice without knowing your data model/requirements. You can technically have a table with no auto increment PK (or even no PK, I'm not 100% sure how mySQL handles this). You might try remove [Key] from your schema and roll this way, but be aware that the performance of selects to this table will suffer unless you have supporting indexes in place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I recently found a way to solve it (but it seems stupid). I set type of 'MaNhom' as string. In C# code, after randomming the value of 'MaNhom' I covert it to string and add into table groups. It works fine. Can't have a table without key, it won't work.